# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make a kick command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that kicks a specified user when prompted. Here's what I have:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)
```

It doesn't seem to be working, any tips?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! What do you mean by this code not working? Did you get any error messages when running this code, and if so could you edit your question to include this?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, it just doesn't... do anything

Comment: I just tried out your code, it should be working. Do you have an `on_message` event anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah I do, why?

Comment: Do your other commands work, or is it just this one having problems?

Comment: It looks like none of my _commands_ are working. I have several on_message events that work fine though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227365/discussion-between-bagle-and-carter-michaelis) to prevent overflow of comments on this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things. Since your `on_message` events are working using `client.event`, this means that you should replace your `bot.command` with `client.command` as seen below:

```py
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.kick(reason=reason)
        kick = discord.Embed(title=f"Kicked {user.name}!", description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=kick)
        await user.send(embed=kick)
```

If your kick command still doesn't work, at the very end of your `on_message` event, you should add `await client.process_commands(message)`. I'll put an example of this below below:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "Test":
        print("recieved")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Hey this worked! (After I poked around for a bit). Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it!